# Retrieve the private IP address of an Azure Database for PostgreSQL Flexible Server using Bicep/ARM

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-postgresql

I want to retrieve the private IP address of an Azure Database for PostgreSQL Flexible Server during deployment with Bicep/ARM.

Is there a property on the Flexible Server object, a child resource, or the private DNS zone that might have that IP?